# Scala: Matching empty sequence against Nil

Tags: scala, collections, pattern-matching, hierarchical

Why does the following:

```
val x: Seq[Any] = Vector.empty
x match {
 case Nil => 1
 case _ => 2
}
```

where `Vector.empty` internally equates to:

```
private[immutable] val NIL = new Vector[Nothing](0, 0, 0)
override def empty[A]: Vector[A] = NIL
```

match `Nil` and return `1`? Isn't `Nil` only a specific subtype of `Seq`?

The answer remains the same if I use the more generic `Seq.empty`. Why is that?

Comment: I think it is because `Vector[Nothing]` and `Nil` are instances of `AbstractSeq[Nothing]`. `Seq.empty` also has the same type.

Answer (score 5):

By [specification](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#stable-identifier-patterns) this pattern matches when `x == Nil`, which for `Seq` [is defined to be](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.4/scala/collection/Seq.html#equals(that:Any):Boolean)

> true if that is a sequence that has the same elements as this sequence in the same order, false otherwise

So `Vector.empty == Nil` is true.

If you actually want to check that you have exactly the `Nil` object in the pattern match, use one of the following ways:

```
case _: Nil.type =>
case x if x eq Nil =>
```